# fopen is duplicating the same line

Tags: php, fopen

I have a file that looks like this:

```
1||Allan||34||male||USA||||55.789.980
2||Georg||32||male||USA||||55.756.180
3||Rocky||21||male||USA||[100][200]||55.183.567
```

I made a function that when executed adds a given number or removes it if already present, which is $added and equals 100 for this example. This is my code:

```
$added = $_GET['added']; //100 for this example

$f = fopen($file, "w");
$list = file($file);
foreach ($list as $line) {
    $details = explode("||", $line);
    if (preg_match("~\b$details[0]\b~", 3)) {
        foreach ($details as $key => $value) {
            if ($key == 5) {
                $newline .= str_replace("[" . $added . "]", "", $value);
            } else {
                $newline .= $value . "||";
            }
        }
        $line = $newline . "\n";
    }
    fputs($f, $line);
}
fclose($f);
}
```

this code is supposed to remove the [100] from the Rocky line since its already present which it kinda does. However, upon further execution instead of adding it back it duplicates the Rocky line and messes it up so the file looks like this:

```
1||Allan||34||male||USA||||55.789.980
2||Georg||32||male||USA||||55.756.180
3||Rocky||21||male||USA||[100][200]55.183.567

3||Rocky||21||male||USA||[100][200]55.183.567 
||
||
```

why is it doing this? I cant make any sense out of it...

Thank you.

Comment: `fopen($file,"w");` empties the file. You shouldn't be getting anything from `file($file)`

Comment: Why do you write `preg_match("~\b$details[0]\b~", 3)` instead of just `$details[0] == "3"`?

Comment: Where do you initialize `$newline`? You should initialize it to an empty string each time through the outer loop.

Comment: Why should this remove `[100]` from the line? It performs the replacement in field 3, but that's in field 5.

Comment: Is it intentional that you don't add `||` after the field when you replace `[100]`?

Comment: I don't think the code you posted is what you're actually running. Please update it.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake when I posted the code but still, it wont work.

Comment: When I try this script I get an empty file because of the first problem.

Comment: where are you running it? yPHP version is 5.6

Comment: If I put `$list = file($file);` first, I get a valid output file, but I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: I'm using php 7.4. But I don't think there have been any changes to any of the operations you're using.

Comment: I dont know. I got that part down right on my side. Maybe you need to store the content of the file inside a variable first?

Comment: Yes, that's the main problem.

Comment: can you do it on your side? I dont know what to change on that regard since that part is working fine here.

Comment: this part `$list = file($file);` include it before fopen.

Comment: Isn't that what I said?

Comment: sorry I hadnt seen your answer at the moment I posted that. Let me try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should read the file before you open it for output, because opening with the `w` mode truncates the file.

Second, you don't need to loop over the fields in `$details` if you just want to change one of them. Just access and assign it by index.

Then you can put the line back together with `implode()`.

```
$list = file($file);
$f = fopen($file, "w");
foreach ($list as $line) {
    $details = explode("||", $line);
    if (preg_match("~\b$details[0]\b~", 3)) {
        if (strpos("[$added]", $details[5]) === false) {
            $details[5] = "[$added]" . $details[5];
        } else {
            $details[5] = str_replace("[$added]", "", $details[5]);
        }
        $line = implode('||', $details)
    }
    fputs($f, $line);
}
fclose($f);
```

Comment: okay, it removes it but it wont add it back when executed it again.

Comment: I added an `if` that adds or removes it depending on whether it's already there.